# Handling Json Objects from SQL server DB at Fastreport

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, fastreport

its my first time using fastreport, i am using FR with a asp.net web api, after searching i have decieded to get the data from db using stored proc. and get whatever pass whatever filter im using from the report from the front-end to the api (example like a certain Id of the object i wanna create a report for) and then pass this value to the stored proc. i export to the FR and pass this value to my parameters, i don't know if this is the best way to use FR with my api so i'm open to any suggestions. Now my main problem is that i have json obj in my SQL DB for localization(ex: the Name obj is stored like that {"en":"TestAcc2","fr":"test"}) so how can i convert a certain language from a field like this to show in the report, i have found resources on how to deal with a whole json DB but i only want to deserlizae this field so any help on how i could do it ?

Comment: Have you tried `NewtonsoftJson` library like [this example](https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/show/multilevel-json/)?

Comment: i can't install any packages in fast report